# When you click on an item you want to fragment the city, but he does not work

Tags: android-fragments

When an item is clicked I want to see the city fragment, but it does not work. 
It works in the navigation menu, but when you click on an item that does not work.

```
public class CityFragment extends Fragment implements CityAdapter.OnOverViewClick {

    //Views
    private RelativeLayout rl;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private View mLoadingView;

    private String cityString;

    //List
    private CityAdapter multipleItemAdapter;

    private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener recyclerListener;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rl = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entekhab_shahr, null);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rl.findViewById(R.id.rv_list);


        final StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        cityString = this.getArguments().getStringArray(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_DATA)[0];

        recyclerListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //Get the view width, and check if it could be valid
                int viewWidth = mRecyclerView.getMeasuredWidth();
                if (viewWidth <= 0) return;

                //Remove the VTO
                mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                //Calculate and update the span
                float cardViewWidth = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.card_width_overview);
                int newSpanCount = Math.max(1, (int) Math.floor(viewWidth / cardViewWidth));
                mLayoutManager.setSpanCount(newSpanCount);
                mLayoutManager.requestLayout();
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(recyclerListener);

        mLoadingView = rl.findViewById(R.id.loading_view);

        //Load items
        loadItems();

        return rl;
    }

    public void loadItems() {
        new CityParser(cityString, getActivity(), new CityParser.CallBack() {
            @Override
            public void categoriesLoaded(ArrayList < NavItem > result, boolean failed) {
                if (failed) {
                    //If it failed; show an error if we're using a local file, or if we are online & using a remote overview.
                    if (!cityString.contains("http") || Helper.isOnlineShowDialog(getActivity()))
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.invalid_configuration, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                //Add all the new posts to the list and notify the adapter
                multipleItemAdapter = new CityAdapter(result, getContext(), CityFragment.this);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(multipleItemAdapter);

                loadCompleted();
            }
        }).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(recyclerListener);
    }

    private void loadCompleted() {
        //Hide the loading view if it isn't already hidden
        if (mLoadingView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            mLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOverViewSelected(NavItem item) {
        HolderActivity.startActivity(getActivity(), item.getFragment(), item.getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: THIS IS MY ACTIVITY       @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.favorites:
                HolderActivity.startActivity(this, CityFragment.class, null);
                return true;


            case R.id.profile:
                HolderActivity.startActivity(this, Profile_Fragment.class, null);
                return true;


            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and Please add this info to your question

Comment: I wanted to add that I worked every error